# What do you call a person who's just been released from jail?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there a specific word for a person who has **just been released** from jail?

Comment: Related :http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150070/what-would-you-call-a-former-criminal-who-has-been-released-from-prison

Answer (score 1):

The OED has no entries relating to "recently released from prison", so I believe the answer to your question is ***No:*** there is no specific word. The closest entry is under *released:*

> **released** *adj*
>
> That has been released (in various senses); *spec.*  (a) revoked or remitted (now chiefly *Law*);  (b) set free or made available (also with modifying adverb) (now the commonest sense).
>
> 1894   *Times* 27 Aug. 4   Dr. Kenny, one of the recently-released suspects, presided.
> 2006   *New Scientist* 29 July 6/4   Prendergast's team studied released convicts in San Diego who had been treated in a prison therapeutic community.

I did find the word ***unprisoned,*** for which the single citation in OED is from Dickens' *The Old Curiosity Shop:*

> Released from prison.
>
> 1841   Dickens *Old Curiosity Shop* ii. lii. 88   Perhaps not one of the unprisoned souls had been able [etc.].

Support agencies use a number of terms such as those listed in the [related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150070/what-would-you-call-a-former-criminal-who-has-been-released-from-prison). [*Step Ahead*](http://www.iseek.org/exoffenders/find-job/common-jobs.html) and the Minnesota Department of Corrections use **newly-released ex-offender:**

> Finding a job is an important part of transition after incarceration. Ideally, you will find a job that matches your skills and interests. The reality is that the first jobs many newly released ex-offenders find do not match their desired careers.

Comment: The OED also has *unjailed*, although its singular citation is from just a decade after the *Mayflower* came over here for the first time.